# Creating a Month End spreadsheet

Tags: python, pandas, merge, concatenation

Probably a simple answer but I am new to coding and this is my first project.

I have managed to sum together the necessary information from individual spreadsheets and would now like to write an 'End of Month' spreadsheet to sum all individual data.

heres what i have so far..

```
import pandas as pd


from pathlib import Path
path = Path("Spreadsheets")
for file in path.glob("*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f"{file}")
    client_total = df.groupby(["Nominal"]).sum()["Amount"]
    print(client_total)
```

This returns

```
Nominal
1118     379
1135    2367
1158     811
Name: Amount, dtype: int64
Nominal
1118    1147.85
1135     422.66
1158     990.68
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
Nominal
1118    736.38
1135    477.40
1158    470.16
Name: Amount, dtype: float64
```

Please let me know how I can merge these three separate results into one easy to read month total.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want to add them together or append?

Comment: Hi Bernard, add them together to get an overall total for each nominal.

Comment: I just added in the answers. please check and let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create list of `Series` called `out` and then use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with sum by index by `sum(level=0)`:

```
out = []
from pathlib import Path
path = Path("Spreadsheets")
for file in path.glob("*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f"{file}")
    client_total = df.groupby(["Nominal"])["Amount"].sum()
    out.append(client_total)

df = pd.concat(out).sum(level=0)
print(df)
```

Comment: @ElliottBuckle The suggested way of saying "This works!" is upvoting the post.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have three dataframes (df1, df2,df3), you can simply use the add function along columns:

```
df_sum=df1.add(df2)
df_sum=df_sum.add(df3)
print(df_sum)
Nominal
1118  2263.23
1135  3267.06
1158  2271.84
```

Hopefully, this can help you:
import pandas as pd

```
from pathlib import Path
path = Path("Spreadsheets")
df_sum=pd.DataFrame(columns=['Nominal'],index=[1118,1135,1158],data=[0,0,0])
for file in path.glob("*.xlsx"):
   df = pd.read_excel(f"{file}")
   client_total = df.groupby(["Nominal"]).sum()["Amount"]
   print(client_total)
   df_sum=df_sum.add(client_total)
print(df_sum)
```

Comment: Amazing! This was just an example I put together however the directory I will be applying this code to with have thousands of data frames to add together. Is there a way of writing it to apply to all df's in the directory?

Comment: @ElliottBuckle - How working `df = pd.concat(out).sum(level=0)` ?

Comment: you can run them in a loop for new dataframes!

Comment: @jezrael IT WORKS!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work?

```
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

path = Path("Spreadsheets")
dfs = []

for file in path.glob("*.xlsx"):
    df = pd.read_excel(f"{file}")
    client_total = df.groupby(["Nominal"]).sum()["Amount"]
    dfs.append(client_total)

df = dfs[0]
for df in dfs[1:]:
    df = df.add(df)

print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for this, it is a step in the right direction however I'm not sure if I explained myself properly.

for example, this returns:
1118 - 378, 1147.85, 736.38

What I would like is those three totals summed together and to return:
1118 - 2263.23

Comment: You did, I just realized it, so I'm working on it now.